# How to get .config folder not to be ignored by .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to create a .gitignore that will ignore everything except from some folders and files. However, I can't get to "unignore" folder that begins with a dot.

This is my `.gitignore`:

```
*
!.gitignore

!.tmux.conf

!.config/lvim/
!.config/nvim/
```

Right now is properly ignoring every file except `.gitignore` and `.tmux.conf` but it wont "unignore" the folders withing `.config/`.

How can I make it to detect these files?

Comment: Note that the "duplicate" is not an *exact* duplicate, but the solution is the same.

Comment: I already went to that post before but I could not get it to work with the answers posted there. I can unignore every folder or file I want except for folders starting with a dot.

Comment: You need `!.config` (with or without a trailing slash) before `!.config/lvim/` etc will work. That's from the first answer.